# The error of Spark job "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext" in Spark Job Server

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark, hive, spark-jobserver

I create a spark job with IntelliJ , and i want it be loaded and run by spark Job-Server. For this i followed the steps in this link : http://github.com/ooyala/spark-jobserver
And the version of my spark is 1.4.0.

This is the scala code in my project :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
//spark job server
import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory}
import scala.util.Try
import spark.jobserver.SparkJob
import spark.jobserver.SparkJobValidation
import spark.jobserver.SparkJobValid
import spark.jobserver.SparkJobInvalid

class hiveSparkRest extends SparkJob {
  var idCard:String =""


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


    val sc = new SparkContext("local[4]", "SmartApp")
    val config = ConfigFactory.parseString("")

    val results = runJob(sc, config)
    println("Result is " + results)


    enterTimesMax(sc, hiveContext)

  }


  override def validate(sc: SparkContext, config: Config): SparkJobValidation = {
    Try(config.getString("input.string"))
      .map(x => SparkJobValid)
      .getOrElse(SparkJobInvalid("No input.string config param"))
  }

  override def runJob(sc: SparkContext,config: Config): Any = {
    idCard = config.getString("input.string")
    enterTimesMax(sc, hiveContext)
  }

  def enterTimesMax(sc:SparkContext,hiveContext:HiveContext): Unit = {
    val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
    hiveContext.sql("use default")

    val sqlUrl = "select max(num) from (select idcard,count(1) as num from passenger group by idcard)as t"

    val idCardArray = hiveContext.sql(sqlUrl).collect()


  }
}
```

But when i execute it i got curl: (52) Empty reply from server with this error in spark job-server:

```
> job-server[ERROR] Uncaught error from thread [JobServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[JobServer]
job-server[ERROR] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext
job-server[ERROR]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
job-server[ERROR]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
job-server[ERROR]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
job-server[ERROR]   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
job-server[ERROR]   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
job-server[ERROR]   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
job-server[ERROR]   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
job-server[ERROR]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
job-server[ERROR]   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
job-server[ERROR]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
job-server[ERROR]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
job-server[ERROR]   at sql.hiveSparkRest.shadePassenger(hiveSparkRest.scala:62)
job-server[ERROR]   at sql.hiveSparkRest.runJob(hiveSparkRest.scala:56)
job-server[ERROR]   at spark.jobserver.JobManagerActor$$anonfun$spark$jobserver$JobManagerActor$$getJobFuture$4.apply(JobManagerActor.scala:222)
job-server[ERROR]   at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
job-server[ERROR]   at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
job-server[ERROR]   at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42)
job-server[ERROR]   at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
job-server[ERROR]   at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
job-server[ERROR]   at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
job-server[ERROR]   at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
job-server[ERROR]   at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
job-server[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
job-server[ERROR]   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
job-server[ERROR]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
job-server[ERROR]   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
job-server[ERROR]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
job-server[ERROR]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
job-server[ERROR]   ... 22 more
job-server ... finished with exit code 255
```

Seems the class HiveContext is supported by spark jar file spark-assembly-1.4.0-hadoop1.0.4.jar.

Comment: Are you sure you have added [spark-sql](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10/1.4.0) JAR dependency?

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida Thx for the help! which spark-sql JAR file do you mean? I think the class SQLContext is supported by spark-assembly-1.4.0-hadoop1.0.4.jar which is the internal jar in Spark.

Comment: The jar that you can find on the link I gave you. You need to add it to your dependency files (pom.xml, build.sbt or equivalent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think ooyala repo is the main one. In the maintained repo, the below link shows a test job for using HiveContext. For SparkHiveJob trait you need jobserver-extras jar.

https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/job-server-extras/src/spark.jobserver/HiveTestJob.scala

Comment: Thanks for Norul's help. I will try it.

Comment: Seems the answer is correct! But when I run my application(my Scala class
 which extends SparkSqlJob), I am getting the following as response:

 {
   "status": "ERROR",
   "result": "Invalid job type for this context"
 }
Can you please help me with this issue?
And I raise a new question to track it, Thanks!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032545/the-error-invalid-job-type-for-this-context-in-spark-sql-job-with-spark-job-se