# The error "Invalid job type for this context" in spark SQL job with Spark job server

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-jobserver

I create a spark SQL job with spark job server and use HiveContext following the sample below:
 https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/job-server-extras/src/spark.jobserver/HiveTestJob.scala

I was able to start the server but when I run my application(my Scala class
 which extends SparkSqlJob), I am getting the following as response:

```
{
   "status": "ERROR",

   "result": "Invalid job type for this context"
 }
```

Can any one suggest me what is going wrong or provide a detailed procedure
 for setting up jobserver for SparkSQL?

The code is below:

```
import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory}
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import spark.jobserver.{SparkJobValid, SparkJobValidation, SparkHiveJob}

object newHiveRest extends SparkHiveJob {


  def validate(hive: HiveContext, config: Config): SparkJobValidation = SparkJobValid

  def runJob(hive: HiveContext, config: Config): Any = {

    hive.sql(s"use default")
    val maxRdd = hive.sql(s"select count(*) from 'default'.'passenger'")

    maxRdd.count()
  }
}
```

Comment: The logs of job server are below:
scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$assertNoOtherContextIsRunning$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:2083)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$assertNoOtherContextIsRunning$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:2065)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.assertNoOtherContextIsRunning(SparkContext.scala:2065)
        at

Answer (score 0):

For Spark SQL you can use the following

https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/job-server-extras/src/spark.jobserver/SqlTestJob.scala

Comment: Thanks for Noorul's help! I actually use the class HiveContext. So I create a job which extends SparkHiveJob. But it failed. I posted the error log of job server in comment.

Comment: Looking at the exception I think it is failing when it asserts for more than one context in spark. Can you verify that?

Comment: Please refer to the code posted in the question. I don't create any sparkContext and just use the HiveContext instance in SparkHiveJob.